# UWP NavigationView hide NavPane on specific "fullscreen" Page

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have very basic NavigationView with frame:

```
<NavigationView
    x:Name="navigationView"
    AlwaysShowHeader="False"
    SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.OnSelectionChanged}">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
    </Grid>
</NavigationView>
```

And simplest EventHandler:

```
public async void OnSelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

        // I'm using Prism framework, by the way...
        navigationService.Navigate(item.Tag.ToString(), null);
    }
```

I want to get the same as done in **Groove Music**, when you navigating to Now Playing - NavPane is hiding, and only appbackbutton is available.
My current solution is to catch OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom events on my FullscreenPage and change NavigationView.CompactPaneLength and NavigationView.OpenPaneLength:

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
    {
        // private field
        // navigationPage = Window.Current.Content as NavigationPage;
        navigationPage.NavigationView.IsPaneToggleButtonVisible = false;
        navigationPage.NavigationView.CompactPaneLength = 0;
        navigationPage.NavigationView.OpenPaneLength = 0;
    }

    public override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingFromEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState, bool suspending)
    {
        navigationPage.NavigationView.IsPaneToggleButtonVisible = true;
        navigationPage.NavigationView.CompactPaneLength = 64;
        navigationPage.NavigationView.OpenPaneLength = 320;
    }
```

It's works as expected, but there is some agly freezes, when NavigationView is "collapsing".
Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Oh, another solution is to use UserControl in NavigationPage (Shell). Wrap FullscreenControl (set higher z-index) and NavigationView up with a Grid (in the same Row and Column) and set FullscreenControl.Visibility to Collapsed. And then, when required, change Visibillity to Visible with Animation.

I try to use multiple frames (navigationFrame inside core app frame) but appbackbutton broke up.

Comment: hi @telepzk ,does the following answer works in your side?

Comment: Hello, @nico-zhu-msft, yep, this works well, but i can't use this solution, because i'm using Prism MVVM, and it wraps frame.Navige by it's own Facade - NavigationService (to resolve dependency and so on). In Prism.WPF there is RegionAdapter, which deals with multiple frames, but there is no this functionality on UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the same as done in Groove Music, when you navigating to Now Playing

The `NavigationView` was displayed in the MainPage's Frame and it contained `ContentFrame` that used to display `FirstPage` and `SecondPage`. If you want to display `PlayPage` and hide `NavigationView`, the better way is that displayed `PlayPage` in the `MainPageFrame` just like the following picture.

[image]

When you back from `PlayPage` to `MainPage`, the `NavigationView` will display automatically, and you need not handle the complex animation for `NavigationView`. Please refer the following code.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

}     
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {

        foreach(NavigationViewItemBase item in NvTest.MenuItems)
        {
          if((string) item.Tag == contentFrame.CurrentSourcePageType.Name)
            {
                SelectItem = item;
            }
        }
    }
    Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

private NavigationViewItemBase selectItem;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{      
    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public NavigationViewItemBase SelectItem
{
    get
    {
        return selectItem;
    }
    set
    {
        selectItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}


private void NvTest_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var selectedItem = (NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem;
    string pageName = "App14." + ((string)selectedItem.Tag);
    if ((string)selectedItem.Tag == "PlayPage")
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(Type.GetType(pageName));

    }
    else
    {
        sender.Header = pageName;
        Type pageType = Type.GetType(pageName);
        contentFrame.Navigate(pageType);              
    }

}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="NvTest" SelectionChanged="NvTest_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectItem,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1" />
            <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Save" Content="Menu Item2" Tag="PlayPage" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Save" Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage2" />

        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

This is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App14.git).